# Client authentication failed; app will be blocked

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-maps-sdk-ios

Im using google map sdk for ios, at first, everything seems to be fine but after a while, i always got this error message and cant access maps api at all.

The error message :
`Client authentication failed; app will be blocked`

I checked my app bundle id on api key page, i also tried to regenerate the api key but keep getting the same error, i even tried to make the entire new project on google cloud console but its not work either. I got frustrated and dont know what todo. If you know something about this,pls tell,  your help is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error "Client authentication failed; app will be blocked", there are many points you need to troubleshoot to find out the root cause. You can start by checking API Key Restrictions and Credentials as mismatches on the settings may cause this error. Also check the permissions in your google cloud console to make sure that access is provisioned properly. Lastly, check the network connectivity and security as it may be hindering communication as well. If the issue persist, you may want to contact support for further assistance.[1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/support